# part of form in modal window with jquery

Tags: jquery, drupal, forms

I have complex form that I want to make more user friendly. It consists of many fieldsets. Can I take one of fieldsets and make it into a modal window without braking form?

My idea is that fieldset is visually replaced by button that triggers modal window that displays replaced part of form in modal window. form must perform same as without modal window, it will do ajax and jquery and all kinds of stuff.

I am looking to improve Drupal ImageFlield UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jQuery UI, I think you will need to make a copy of the fieldset and use JS to insert the values from it back to the form. jQuery will move the content into some special divs, so it will break the form.

Drupal is very strict about not allowing it's forms to be edited.

Comment: flase alarm, thanks for your time! there is module for that... http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_imagefield

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subform element as in the Subform module, http://drupal.org/project/subform.

Answer (score 0):

Im not too familiar with Drupal, but if I were just doing plain old jQuery, I might have a secondary form in the modal div. When the secondary form is submitted, it updates the appropriate fields on the primary form.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://drupal.org/project/modalframe_cck_editor